# Angular Child Routes

Tags: angular

I want to create a child route that uses the same component as it's parent. So for example using the below routes, would all point to the same Component. The component then decides what to do depending in the route.

```
work/
work/project-title1
work/project-title2
```

The reason being Work is using ThreeJS and the two different Views (routes) are intrinsically tied to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  {path: 'work', children: [
        {path: '', component: WorkComponent},
        {path: 'project-title1', redirectTo: ''},
        {path: 'project-title2', redirectTo: ''}
    ]}
```

Comment: this redirects the URL to just /work, I would want to keep the URL with the project title.

Comment: I've tried this ` {path: 'work', data: { state: 'work' }, children: [
      {path: '', component: WorkComponent},
      {path: '**',component: WorkComponent},
    ]},`

But when navigating through Brower Back & Forward, it still reloads the Page/Component